# How to use R-Tree of NetTopologySuite in GMap.NET to display abundant marker WPF

Tags: wpf, google-maps-markers, gmap.net, r-tree, nettopologysuite

I am using GMap.NET to display a lot of Marker (about more than 10.000 markers). R-Tree is a solution to optimize render markers at area which window is showing.

STRtree in NetTopologySuite is a library to support R-tree. But I'm not sure it suitable for this problem.

My question is how to use R-Tree in NetTopologySuite to show markers. I don't know how to use library. (I'm new in WPF). How to catch event when GMap render marker to **get** marker from R-Tree and remove previous marker at same time?

Please give me some example about R-tree in NetTopologySuite.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by my way. This is the way STRtree is decleared:        `STRtree<Coordinate> gpsSTRtree = new STRtree<Coordinate>();` You can change `Coordinate` data type by any other data type but STRtree need to `Envelope` to insert to tree.

For example: insert to STRtree: 
`Coordinate gps = new Coordinate(9.74233, 106.0213);
Envelope item = new Envelope(gps);
gpsSTRtree.Insert(item, gps);`

Envelope is a node in STRtree to store the *boundary* of item.

STRtree query from two points. `point1` and `point2` are `Coordinate`

`Envelope gpsQuery = new Envelope(p1, p2);
Coordinate gpsItems = gpsSTRtree.Query(gpsQuery);`

Then you have a list of `Coordinate`

Good luck